# How do I move the range of data filtered by a VBA macro?

Tags: vba, excel, filter, macros

I am currently using this code to filter a range in column A (starting in cell 1 and going to cell 600). It will leave only values starting with a number.

```
Sub WildAutofilter()
    Dim data As Range, c As Collection
    Dim v As String, i As Long, ary
    Set data = Range("A1:A23")
    Set c = New Collection

    On Error Resume Next
        For i = 2 To 600
            v = Cells(i, 1).Value
            If Left(v, 1) = "1" Or Left(v, 1) = "2" Or Left(v, 1) = "3" Or Left(v, 1) = "4" Or Left(v, 1) = "5" Or Left(v, 1) = "6" Or Left(v, 1) = "7" Or Left(v, 1) = "8" Or Left(v, 1) = "9" Then
                c.Add v, CStr(v)
            End If
        Next i
    On Error GoTo 0

    ReDim ary(3 To c.Count - 1)
    For i = 4 To c.Count
        ary(i - 1) = c.Item(i)
    Next i

    With ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$23")
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=(ary), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End With
End Sub
```

This code works fine for this location but the data that I actually want to filter is in column C, Starting in cell 3. I have tried to alter the code to the following:

```
Sub WildAutofilter()
    Dim data As Range, c As Collection
    Dim v As String, i As Long, ary
    Set data = Range("C3:C26")
    Set c = New Collection

    On Error Resume Next
        For i = 4 To 600
            v = Cells(i, 3).Value
            If Left(v, 3) = "1" Or Left(v, 3) = "2" Or Left(v, 3) = "3" Or Left(v, 3) = "4" Or Left(v, 3) = "5" Or Left(v, 3) = "6" Or Left(v, 3) = "7" Or Left(v, 3) = "8" Or Left(v, 3) = "9" Then
                c.Add v, CStr(v)
            End If
        Next i
    On Error GoTo 0

    ReDim ary(0 To c.Count - 1)
    For i = 1 To c.Count
        ary(i - 1) = c.Item(i)
    Next i

    With ActiveSheet.Range("$C$3:$C$26")
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=(ary), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End With
End Sub
```

This always returns a subscript out of range error and highlights this line "ReDim ary(0 To c.Count - 1)". I am not very advanced at visual basic. Most of my experience is in 'Frankensteining' other peoples code to make it do what I want, which is exactly what I did with this code. I'm not sure if I am just not changing the right references but if someone could help me out with this, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried any of the answers given here ? people here have given an effort to help you solve your problem, the minimum you can do is to give a feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very nearly there with converting this but what you did as well is you changed the if conditions (I think by mistake). As you changed all of the `1's` to `3's` you also change the string manipulation so instead of `if 1 = 1 then` you were doing `if 1 = 1xx` and so it was never populating your collection.

Below should be fixed. You should also probably put in some error handling in case your if condition does fail for a valid reason in future as well

```
Sub WildAutofilter()
    Dim data As Range, c As Collection
    Dim v As String, i As Long, ary
    Set data = Range("C3:C26")
    Set c = New Collection

    On Error Resume Next
        For i = 4 To 600
            v = Cells(i, 3).Value
            If Left(v, 1) = "1" Or Left(v, 1) = "2" Or Left(v, 1) = "3" _
            Or Left(v, 1) = "4" Or Left(v, 1) = "5" Or Left(v, 1) = "6" _
            Or Left(v, 1) = "7" Or Left(v, 1) = "8" Or Left(v, 1) = "9" Then
                c.Add v, CStr(v)
            End If
        Next i
    On Error GoTo 0

    ReDim ary(0 To c.Count - 1)
    For i = 1 To c.Count
        ary(i - 1) = c.Item(i)
    Next i

    With ActiveSheet.Range("$C$3:$C$26")
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=(ary), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End With
End Sub
```

Just to add to this `Left` is used like:
    `Left('string to manipulate', how many characters to keep)`

Please have a look at the comments below as well to see other solutions to have a more manageable `if` statement

Comment: why not use `Select Case Left(v, 3)` and then on the following line `Case "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"` , it will be shorter (and easier onthe eye)

Comment: @ShaiRado I was going to change it but decided for the OP it would be easier to explain it using the same syntax as they've used. You could use `If instr(1, "123456789", Left(v,1))` as well or even `Select Case CInt(Left(v,1))` and then `Case 1 to 9` with handling for the possibility of  `CInt` failing. There are many ways to skin a cat after all

Comment: Thanks this solved it but I did later switch to @Shai Rado's code as it did keep things simpler

Comment: @ConnorHoward do'nt forget to mark my answer with the little **V**

Answer (score 0):

First, you should accept @Tom answer, as it is correct.

I just wanted to share a cleaner and shorter version of code for you to adapt (for future cases).

Instead of using that very long `If` with 9 possible values for the same criteria, use `Select`.

Second, there is no need to copy the values to a collection, and then have another `For` loop to copy the `Collection` to an array . You can just use an `ary` with late binding, and later on just use `Redim Preserve` everytime you need to resize the array and add another element.

### Code

(edited - thanks to Tom comments)

```
Sub WildAutofilter()

Dim Data As Range
Dim v As String, i As Long
Dim ary()
Dim arycounter  As Long

Set Data = Range("C3:C26")
Set c = New Collection

' initialize the size of the array to maximum
ReDim ary(1 To 1000)
arycounter = 1

On Error Resume Next
For i = 4 To 600
    v = Cells(i, 3).Value

    Select Case Left(v, 1)
        Case "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"
            ary(arycounter) = CStr(v)
            arycounter = arycounter + 1

    End Select

Next i
On Error GoTo 0

' resize array to number of matches found in the loop
ReDim Preserve ary(1 To arycounter - 1)

With Data
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=(ary), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Just a performance tip. `ReDim Preserve` slows your loop down a lot. It is usually more efficient to `Dim` it to the max size then `ReDim` at the end. I'd initiate the ary with `ReDim ary(1 to 600)` before your loop begins and then `ReDim Preserve ary(1 to arycounter-1)` after your loop has ended. Makes a noticeable difference on larger data sets

Comment: @Tom thanks :) have you got the chance to actualy Bench mark these 2 options ? I wonder by how much

Comment: I've quickly put an example together - To do a `Mod 2` of 1 to 1 million `ReDimming` inside the loop takes around 25-30 seconds where as `Dimming` before and then `ReDimming` after the loop takes around 5-10 seconds. I'll happily share my test book if you like

Comment: [ReDim During vs ReDim After example.xlsm](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pd2dif4dc9kmmme/ReDim%20During%20vs%20ReDim%20After%20example.xlsm?dl=1)

Answer (score 0):

How does `Range("$C$3:$C$26")` correlate with "between 2 to 600 rows"?  I define a dynamic range that will resize itself to your list.

```
Sub WildAutofilter()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim FilterArray
    Dim x As Long

    Dim c As Collection
    Set c = New Collection

    With ActiveSheet
        With .Range("C3", .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            ReDim FilterArray(.Cells.Count)
            For Each r In .Cells
                If r.Text Like "[1-9]*" Then
                    On Error Resume Next
                    c.Add vbNullString, r.Text
                    If Err = 0 Then
                        FilterArray(x) = r.Text
                        x = x + 1
                    End If
                    On Error GoTo 0
                End If
            Next
            ReDim Preserve FilterArray(x)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=FilterArray, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what is in your collection so have not tested this. But try reversing the loop so you do not have to redimension

```
Sub WildAutofilter()
Dim data As Range, c As Collection
Dim v As String, i As Long, ary
Set data = Range("C3:C26")
Set c = New Collection

On Error Resume Next
    For i = 600 To 4 Step -1
        v = Cells(i, 3).Value
        If Left(v, 3) = "1" Or Left(v, 3) = "2" Or Left(v, 3) = "3" Or Left(v, 3) = "4" Or Left(v, 3) = "5" Or Left(v, 3) = "6" Or Left(v, 3) = "7" Or Left(v, 3) = "8" Or Left(v, 3) = "9" Then
            c.Add v, CStr(v)
        End If
    Next i
On Error GoTo 0


For i = c.Count To 1
    ary(i) = c.Item(i-1)
Next i

With ActiveSheet.Range("$C$3:$C$26")
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=(ary), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End With
End Sub
```